# Как из listBox получить все отмеченные checkBox?WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
    xmlns:chartingToolkit="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit" x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="637" Width="1889">
<Grid RenderTransformOrigin="0.505,0.844" Margin="0,0,0,19">
    <CheckBox x:Name="cbFilter" Content="CheckBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="15,410,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" Height="25"/>
    <ComboBox x:Name="cbFilterMode" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="95,410,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120">
        <TextBlock>=</TextBlock>

        <TabItem/>
    </ComboBox>
    <TextBox x:Name="txtFilterValue" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="225,409,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
    <GroupBox x:Name="groupBox" Header="GroupBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="225,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1110" Height="385">
        <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="245,105,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="230" Width="645"/>
    </GroupBox>
    <ListBox x:Name="listBox"   HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="385" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="230" FontFamily="Segoe UI Black" Grid.Column="10">


        <ListBox.ItemTemplate >
            <DataTemplate>
                <CheckBox x:Name="qqq"  Content="{Binding }" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" Click="CheckBox_Click"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>


    </ListBox>


</Grid>
```

Получается вывести только все сразу,а как сделать что бы выводилось по одной(т.е. если checkBox==true, то выводим данное измерение из cube)

```
  private void CheckBox_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        var cb = sender as CheckBox;
        var item = cb.IsChecked;
        listBox.SelectedItem = item;

         if (listBox.SelectedIndex==0) return;


        // первая часть запроса: количсество обращений
        string query = "SELECT NON EMPTY { [Measures].[Число Подписки] } ON COLUMNS, NON EMPTY {(";
        // если установлен фильтр - добавляем его


        // перебираем все отмеченные измерения и добавляем их к запросу
        foreach (string i in listBox.Checked)
        {
            query += " " + i.ToString() + ".ALLMEMBERS *";

        }

        // удаляем последний пробел со звездочкой
        query = query.Remove(query.Length - 2);




        //финальная часть запроса
        query += " )} DIMENSION PROPERTIES MEMBER_CAPTION, MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME ON ROWS FROM [Почта] CELL PROPERTIES VALUE, BACK_COLOR, FORE_COLOR, FORMATTED_VALUE, FORMAT_STRING, FONT_NAME, FONT_SIZE, FONT_FLAGS";
        UpdateChart(query);


    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете использовать Linq, выбрав все элементы, у которых `IsChecked == true`

В качестве примера: ListBox с несколькими элементами, имеющими свойство IsChecked. Выбираются те элементы, у которых `IsChecked == true`

**XAML**

```
<ListBox x:Name="CheckBoxes" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

**CODE**

```
public class CheckBoxViewModel {
    public CheckBoxViewModel(bool isChecked) {
        IsChecked = isChecked;
    }

    public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
}

public class Content {
    public Content() {
        items = new List<CheckBoxViewModel> {
            new CheckBoxViewModel(true),
            new CheckBoxViewModel(true),
            new CheckBoxViewModel(true),
            new CheckBoxViewModel(true),
            new CheckBoxViewModel(false),
            new CheckBoxViewModel(true),
            new CheckBoxViewModel(false)
        };
    }

    readonly IEnumerable<CheckBoxViewModel> items;
    public IEnumerable<CheckBoxViewModel> Items { get { return items; } }
}

public partial class MainWindow : Window {
    public MainWindow() {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new Content();
        CheckBoxes.MouseDoubleClick += (s, e) => {
            // Получаем список элементов, у которых IsChecked == true
            var items = CheckBoxes.Items.Cast<CheckBoxViewModel>().Where(x => x.IsChecked);
        };
    }
}
```